# removing a pattern from a list items in python

Tags: python, list

My list has 15 items, all of them contains the word '_new' in the end. So I want to create folders with names of the items without '_new' in it. How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to remove the last 4 characters:

```
[name[:-4] for name in list_of_names]
```

If only some of the names contain `_new` at the end, use a conditional expression:

```
[name[:-4] if name.endswith('_new') else name for name in list_of_names]
```

Comment: Maybe little better `[name.rstrip('_new') if name.endswith('_new') else name for name in list_of_names]`?

Comment: @sheh... nope - it's plain wrong - try it on a file called `_____newnewnew___new`

Comment: @sheh: No, because `.rstrip()` takes a *set* of characters. It'll remove *all* `_`, `n`, `e` and `w` characters, in any order, from the end. Try with `'know_when_we'`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for the regex then:

```
import re
new = [re.sub('_new$', '', fname) for fname in your_list]
```

However you correct your name, you'll want to use [os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) to create it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use strip method with list comprehension to remove "_new":**

```
import os
path = r"C:\Program Files\mypath"
[os.makedirs(os.path.join(path,str(name.strip("_new"))) for name in name_list if os.path.exists(path)]
```